# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Can't buy Coffee for free'

Tags: solidity, hardhat

deploy.js ->

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
const { utils } = require('hardhat');

// Returns the ether balance of a given address.
async function getBalance(address) {
  const balanceBigInt = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(address);
  return ethers.formatEther(balanceBigInt);
}

// Logs the Ether balances for a list of addresses.   
async function printBalances(addresses) {
  let index = 0;
  for (const address of addresses) {
    console.log(`Addresses ${index} balance: `, await getBalance(address));
    index++;
  }
}

// Logs the memos stored on-chain from coffee purchases.
async function printMemos(memos) {
  for (const memo of memos) {
    const timestamp = memo.timestamp;
    const tipper = memo.name;
    const tipperAddress = memo.from;
    const message = memo.message;
    console.log(`At ${timestamp}, ${tipper} (${tipperAddress}) said: "${message}"`);
  }
}

async function main() {
  const [owner, tipper, tipper2, tipper3] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  // const BuyMeACoffee = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("BuyMeACoffee");
  const buyMeACoffee = await hre.ethers.deployContract("BuyMeACoffee");
  // Deploy the contract.
  await buyMeACoffee.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("BuyMeACoffee deployed to:", buyMeACoffee.target);
  console.log("5");
  // Check balances before the coffee purchase.
  const addresses = [owner.address, tipper.address, buyMeACoffee.target];
  console.log("== start ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Buy the owner a few coffees.
  // Error somewhere in tips
  const tip = { value: ethers.parseEther("1") };
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper).buyCoffee("Rahul", "You're a good coder", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper2).buyCoffee("Suprit", "You're a good coder", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper3).buyCoffee("Prasad", "You're a good coder", tip);

  // Check balances after the coffee purchase.
  console.log("== bought coffee ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Withdraw.
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(owner).withdrawTips();

  // Check balances after withdrawal.
  console.log("== withdrawTips ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Check out the memos.
  console.log("== memos ==");
  const memos = await buyMeACoffee.getMemos();
  printMemos(memos);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

BuyMeACoffee.sol ->

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract BuyMeACoffee {
    // Events notify external users, such as a listening frontend website that something has happenned on the blockchain.
    event NewMemo (
        address indexed from,
        uint256 timestamp,
        string name, 
        string message,
        string CoffeeType
    );
    // Creating a struct
    struct Memo {
        address from;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string name;
        string message;
        string CoffeeType;
    }

    address payable owner;

    // creating memos
    Memo[] memos;

    constructor(){
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    // fetching all stored memos
    function getMemos() public view returns (Memo[] memory){
        return memos;
    }

    function buyCoffee(string memory _name, string memory _message, string memory _CoffeeType) public payable{
        require(msg.value > 0, "Can't buy Coffee for free");

        memos.push(Memo(
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp,
            _name,
            _message, 
            _CoffeeType
        ));

        emit NewMemo(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _name, _message, _CoffeeType);
    }
    // sends the entire balance stored in this contract to the owner
    function withdrawTips() public {
        require(owner.send(address(this).balance));
    }

    function updateWithdraw(address _newAddress) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this method");
        owner = payable(_newAddress);
    }

    function buyLargeCoffee (
        string memory _name,
        string memory _message,
        string memory _coffeeType
    ) public payable {
        require(msg.value == 0.03 ether, "Pay 0.03 to buy coffee");
        memos.push(
            Memo(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _name, _message, _coffeeType)
        );

        emit NewMemo(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _name, _message, _coffeeType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is failing because you are passing the value as an argument but you are never sending the real ether with the call.

The function should be called like this:

```
 await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper).buyCoffee("Rahul", "You're a good coder","CoffeType", { value : tip});
```

Here the third argument in the contract is a string but you were passing an integer, and after that you need to mention the value as well which I have done.

Let me know if that was clear.

Comment: after doing that this error comes up -> TypeError: invalid BigNumberish value (argument="request.value", value={ "value": 1000000000000000000 }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.7.0)

Comment: yeah sorry for the misunderstanding, you can add the string argument before tip in your old code and that should work. Other wise directly pass the tip object in instead of storing it

Comment: Thanks for helping.